# Js, Ajax, Json - How not to insert "Array" into db from autocomplete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

im building a little script that will automatically fill few input fields based on autocomplete of the first input field.

I have the script working, but when i hit submit button everything seems to be ok, But when i look into the db to see what was inserted, All fields are inserted with "Array"  instead of what supposed to be inserted. on the autocomplete, I can see that field are being field with the right info, But i guess php doesn't understand what it is, and inserts "Array" instead.

Any ideas how to fix it?

my form:

```
<form action="job_post.php" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group has-success col-md-3">
                    <label class="control-label" for="inputSuccess1">First Name: </label>
                    <input type='text' id='firstname' name='firstname[]'/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group has-success col-md-3">
                    <label class="control-label" for="inputSuccess1">Last Name: </label>
                    <input type='text' id='lastname' name='lastname[]'/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group has-success col-md-3">
                    <label class="control-label" for="inputSuccess1">Age: </label>
                    <input type='text' id='age' name='age[]'/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group has-success col-md-3">
                    <label class="control-label" for="inputSuccess1">Company Name: </label>
                    <input type='text' id='CoName' name='CoName[]'/>
                </div>

<input type="submit">
</form>
```

My job_post.php

```
<?php

require_once 'db_connect.php';

$firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
$lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
$age=$_POST['age'];
$CoName=$_POST['CoName'];

$qry=mysql_query("INSERT INTO jobs (FirstName, LastName, Age, CoName)
VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$age', '$CoName')", $con);
if(!$qry)
{
mysql_close($con);
die("Query Failed: ". mysql_error());
}

else
{
mysql_close($con);
header("Location:index.php");
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

My Js:

```
$('#firstname').autocomplete({
                    source: function( request, response ) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url : 'ajax.php',
                            dataType: "json",
                            data: {
                               name_startsWith: request.term,
                               type: 'firstname',
                               row_num : 1
                            },
                             success: function( data ) {
                                 response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                                    var code = item.split("|");
                                    return {
                                        label: code[0],
                                        value: code[0],
                                        data : item
                                    }
                                }));
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    autoFocus: true,            
                    minLength: 2,
                    select: function( event, ui ) {
                        var names = ui.item.data.split("|");
                        console.log(names[1], names[2], names[3]);                      
                        $('#lastname').val(names[1]);
                        $('#age').val(names[2]);
                        $('#CoName').val(names[3]);
                    }               
                  });
```

My Ajax:

```
<?php
/*
Site : http:www.smarttutorials.net
Author :muni
*/
require_once 'db_connect.php';

if($_GET['type'] == 'firstname'){
    $row_num = $_GET['row_num'];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT FirstName, LastName, Age, CoName FROM jobs where FirstName LIKE '".strtoupper($_GET['name_startsWith'])."%'");    
    $data = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $name = $row['FirstName'].'|'.$row['LastName'].'|'.$row['Age'].'|'.$row['CoName'].'|'.$row_num;
        array_push($data, $name);   
    }   
    echo json_encode($data);
}


?>
```

It does pull data, but im looking to insert it to the db with submit button.

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: You should be using PDO my friend. http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: yes, i know that ill get to that later, I just want to finish the script so that it works the way i need it, Ill wory about PDO later. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated info**

Then place the variables in the query you have now.

Page redone:

```
 <?php

    require_once 'db_connect.php';

    $firstname = $_POST["firstname"][0];
    $CoName = $_POST["CoName"][0]; 

    /*
     * Last Name and Age are not in the array, I removed them from the query 
     * however you need to place them in the array if you wish to add them
     */

    $qry=mysql_query("INSERT INTO jobs (FirstName, CoName)
        VALUES ('$firstname', '$CoName')", $con);

    if(!$qry) {
        mysql_close($con);
        die("Query Failed: ". mysql_error());
    } else {
        mysql_close($con);
        header("Location: index.php");
    }

    ?>
```

Updated again, misread array.

Comment: Script fully working now.

I really apriciate your help.

In this case, I might have a question to you, This scripts now selects whats in table cold companies, thats where the contact info is, If there is no record, how can i update table companies with what was typed in, and then send the whole form to table orders?

Comment: im thinking maybe save to companies if inut CoName is filed or typed? if there is no CoName do not save in companies?

Comment: You would just use an if statement to check if the query out was there. If not then you could add the data to the database using an INSERT query like with the job_post.php.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you are getting single record, for this use limit 1 in your sql(not good idea). otherwise loop through return array for multiple insertion. before inserting use `print_r($_POST);` and see what you are trying to insert.

Comment: OP said it does pull data but he wants to place it in a database. Please read the post.